# Find & Replace inside a compiled .jar file. And then downloading it

Tags: java, php, find-replace

So basically what I want: find and replace strings in a .jar file whatever length it is. It works for me fine except I need to have the same length of the replaced variable as the variable. I want that the length doesn't matter. Does anyone know how to help me?

PHP code:

```php
<?php
$search1 = '%%__NONCE__%%';
$replace1 = 'ME_0000000001';
$search2 = '%%__USER__%%';
$replace2 = '000000000001';
$search3 = '%%__RESOURCE__%%';
$replace3 = '1';

function modifyzip($archive, $search, $replace) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $status = $zip->open($archive);

//    echo $status;

    if ($status == true) {
        /* Get the count of files BEFORE the loop */
        $filecount = $zip->numFiles;

//        echo $filecount;

        for ($i=0; $i < $filecount; $i++) {
            $name = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
            $content = $zip->getFromName($name);
            $edited = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
            if ($edited != $content) {
//                echo $edited;
//                echo $edited . "\n\n";
            }
            $zip->deleteName($name);
            $zip->addFromString($name, $edited);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
}


$templateFilename = 'zips/a.jar';
$inputFilename = 'zips/b.jar';

if (!copy($templateFilename, $inputFilename)) {
    die("Could not copy '$templateFilename' to '$inputFilename'");
}

call_user_func('modifyzip', $inputFilename, $search1, $replace1);
call_user_func('modifyzip', $inputFilename, $search2, $replace2);
call_user_func('modifyzip', $inputFilename, $search3, $replace3);

//echo file_get_contents($templateFilename);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$inputFilename");
header("Content-Type: application/java-archive");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

// read the file from disk
readfile($inputFilename);

unlink($inputFilename);
```

Java Luyten error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 'value' must be in the range [1, 18], but value was: 0.
    at com.strobel.core.VerifyArgument.inRange(VerifyArgument.java:346)
    at com.strobel.assembler.ir.ConstantPool$Tag.fromValue(ConstantPool.java:532)
    at com.strobel.assembler.ir.ConstantPool.read(ConstantPool.java:362)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.JarTypeLoader.getInternalNameFromClassFile(JarTypeLoader.java:105)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.JarTypeLoader.tryLoadType(JarTypeLoader.java:78)
    at us.deathmarine.luyten.LuytenTypeLoader.tryLoadType(LuytenTypeLoader.java:25)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.MetadataSystem.resolveType(MetadataSystem.java:120)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.MetadataSystem.lookupTypeCore(MetadataSystem.java:81)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.MetadataResolver.lookupType(MetadataResolver.java:46)
    at us.deathmarine.luyten.Model.openEntryByTreePath(Model.java:338)
    at us.deathmarine.luyten.Model$TreeListener$1.run(Model.java:266)
```

Comment: You can't just change strings like that, the file format includes length fields and offsets  that point to different things in the file. In the general case you need to parse the file format, do the change in the parsed representation, and recreate the file. 
What are you trying do, where do you expect to find these strings?

Comment: The string values will be auto generated by another code later. The variables can be in multiple .class files of my .jar file. I need to change it to be able to run some code in my .jar file.

Comment: Where in the class files do you expect to find these strings? Do you expect to be making arbitrary changes to the code such as replacing one implementation of a Java function with another, or adding or removing features, or is this strictly limited to something like changing the values of constant fields?

Comment: Just to change values of constant fields. They will be only readable.